# How to migrate all packages, settings, user data etc. after updating to a newer Python version?

Tags: python, updates, package-management, migration, packages

I've just installed Python 3.10 on Windows 10 and none of my scripts are working. For instance, when doing `jupyter notebook` I get

```
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've been using Python 3.9 and all the scripts are still located in `C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts`. However, there is nothing in `C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts` (besides `pip`).

As a first attempt to solve the problem, I uninstalled Python 3.10 leaving only 3.9. But this didn't help - meaning that **installing a newer Python version will brick your entire developing framework**!

Question:

- What is the optimal way to get everything back operational, do I have to migrate everything from 3.9 directories to 3.10 directories? I.e. would it suffice to just copy over the content of the `\Scripts` folder to the newer version or are there more folders scattered about?
- And what about all the customizations done to packages, e.g. user settings in `Jupyter`, how can they be preserved/migrated?

I'm a little surprised that Python doesn't handle this issues automatically, i.e. keep itself "stateless" and save all packages into a separate ("stateful") user folder, then just automatically add this user folder to the Python path. Isn't it wildly irresponsible to have updates brick the entire development framework?

The way it is handled now seems like a productivity killer. I don't want to reinstall and reconfigure my entire code base, all packages, dependencies, settings etc. every time there is a new Python version. *Surely* there must be an "orthodox" way how this is dealt with properly?

Comment: Why didn't you install into C:\Program Files\Python39? For example you can keep a permanent python folder as C:\Python3 and install every minor version in said directory. Some things will break and require reinstallation however.

Comment: @misantroop What are you referring to, the Python update or the Python packages? If you mean the former, why on earth would I ever install anything on top of something else, i.e. into the same Windows folder, unless this was common practise for a specific piece of software? Also, what is the folder structure you're thinking about, is it `\Python3` with subfolders `\Python3\Python39`, `\Python3\Python310` etc.?

Comment: Installing all Python3x into the same directory. You run the risk of version incompatibility either way.

Comment: @misantroop Won't this get all kinds of files replaced randomly?? How is this supposed to help

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was crossposted on [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can report a partial success in rescuing my working system: Uninstalling the newer Python version, removing all newly added PATH entries and rebooting seems at least to get Jupyter back operational.

**This means that installing newer Python version will only *soft*-brick your system.** Removing updates may restore the functioning of your old version. Maybe this will help somebody struggling with the same problem.

This, of course, doesn't solve the issue of updating and migrating your packages - or give a solution to what is the proper, canonical, orthodox way for "moving your stuff".

**Conclusion**: [***"Python packaging in general is such a messy ecosystem (...) It’s probably worst in class."***](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21781604)